# How to convert character string to time

Tags: r, time-format

I have a column of strings in the format '17:24:00'. I want to convert into time format. When I am using strptime function, it is adding date in front of time. I don't want that to happen. Anyone knows how to avoid adding date.

```
chr [1:2075259] "17:24:00" "17:25:00" "17:26:00" "17:27:00" "17:28:00" ...
```

I tried this -

```
hpc$time<-strptime(hpc$time,format='%H:%M:%S')
```

It gave me the following result -

```
POSIXlt[1:2075259], format: "2020-06-15 17:24:00" "2020-06-15 17:25:00" "2020-06-15 17:26:00" ...
```